# How to convert a boolean 3D array to an int array?

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, boolean

I need to convert a 3D True/False into 1/0

For ex:

```
x = np.array([0,0,-1,1,0,1,-1,1,0]).reshape(3,3)[:, np.newaxis]
```

I tried the methods which are used to convert array

```
[x>0]*1
```

But it gives only the boolean values,

```
[array([[[False, False, False]],

        [[ True, False,  True]],

        [[False,  True, False]]])]
```

Is there a way to convert this while keeping the structure of the matrix?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC this should work:

```
(x>0).astype(int)

array([[[0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0]]])
```

or, what you did, but without forcing it into a list with the square brackets:

```
(x>0)*1

array([[[0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would used `map()` function.
Let's say the array is `test` and `z` the condition.

`map(lambda x: map(lambda y: map(lambda z: int(z), y), x), test)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with from reading the docs.

```
'''
OP wants to convert a 3 dimensional numpy array from
the Boolean array, to an int array. Use the astype
function and pass int to the function in order to
convert the array to the integer type
'''

import numpy as np
x = np.array([0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0]).reshape(3, 3)[:, np.newaxis]
x = x.astype(int)
print(x)
```

The astype function is what you can use in this situation, and you can pass int to it in order to convert the array to an integer array. Also from the docs, this can be used with any array (for example also works for a 2x2, 1x1 ect) if you ever need to use it again in the future. I didn't use a jupyter notebook, but when I printed x in a Python script, the output was what you were looking for.